# "Access Denied" When ECS Fargate Task Tries to Upload to S3 via Presigned URL

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, amazon-kms, pre-signed-url

My fargate task runs a script which calls an API that creates a presigned url. With this presigned url info, I send a PUT http request to upload a file to an s3 bucket. I checked the logs for the task run and I see that it the request gets met with an Access Denied. So I tested it locally (without any permissions) and confirmed that it works and uploads the file properly. I'm not sure what's incorrect permission-wise in the ecs task since the local doesn't even need any permissions to upload the file, since the presigned url provides all the needed permissions for it.

I'm at my wits end, I've provided KMS and full S3 access to my task role (not my task execution role), for the bucket and the objects (* and /*)

Is there something wrong with the presigned url implementation or my VPC config? It should allow all outbound requests without restriction.

Thanks for helping

Comment: You have not provided any code, so we can't really offer any specific advice. You say that you "tested it locally" -- are you referring to the pre-signed URL? If so, then the problem is not with the pre-signed URL. You would need to check how the PUT request uses the pre-signed URL.

Comment: If the problem was your VPC config, you would get a request timeout or some other network error, not a permission error. My guess is your code is trying to authenticate the upload with the ECS task's IAM role, which is causing the issue. However, like John said, without seeing your code, there's nothing we can really help with.